# File::copyDirectory return nothing

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm able to copy files using Storage::copy but when i tried to copy folder with File::copyDirectory, it doesn't change anything. Why is that?

My Code:

```
 public function pasteDocument(Request $request)
    {      
      if(Session::get('clipboard') == "copy"){
      // copy to disk
          File::copyDirectory('public\img', 'public\js', true);
         }
      return redirect()->back();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass full paths to `copyDirectory()`:

```
File::copyDirectory(public_path('img'), public_path('js'), true);
```

Comment: Tried to change to `File::copyDirectory("C:\laragon\www\SMM\public('img')", "C:\laragon\www\SMM\public('js')", true);` still nothing happen. Did i write it wrong?

Comment: @DiknaRYahdi because your code is wrong. Why don't you just copy and paste my code?

Comment: I guess i misinterpret your code haha Thx for the help, it works!!